# How to zoom lines drawn with Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, zooming, android-view, pinchzoom

I'm using an library called ImageTouchView to have pinch zooming feature in my application. But whenever I use Canvas to draw a line on it, the drawn line does not zoom in/out, it just stays with the same size. 
How am I be able to also zooming the drawn line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. To do it, I had to get the Canvas draw (with all lines I want) and convert it to an bitmap. Then I set this bitmap to the ImageView bitmap. Works like a charm!